# Popup a window if checkbox is checked in Yii

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, checkbox, yii

I will appreciate if somebody could help me to find how to solve out one problem, I have a checkbox in my create form. If i pushed the create button I want to have a popup window if the checkbox is checked and do nothing if the checkbox is unchecked.

Here is what I started.

```
<?php echo $form->checkBoxRow($model, 'default'); ?>

<div class="form-actions">
    <?php $this->widget('bootstrap.widgets.TbButton', array(
        'buttonType'=>'submit',
        'type'=>'primary',
        'label'=>$model->isNewRecord ? 'Create' : 'Save',
    )); ?>
 </div>
```

help me with this please

Comment: you want use jQuery or Yii ? what have you tried so far ?

Comment: I tried it in a different way. I put the popup in my create button. and put my create in the popup. but it doesnt make sense.

Answer (score 0):

Use this to check if check box is checked

```
$('#create').click(function(){
    if ($('#checkbox').is(':checked')) {
        //Show your dialog over here
    }
});
```

Comment: Or `$("#myCheckbox").prop("checked");`.

Comment: like this sir?
<?php echo $form->checkBoxRow($model, 'default'); ?>
<script>

    if ($('#default').prop("checked")) {
        <?php
        $this->widget('bootstrap.widgets.TbButton', array(
            'label'=>'Click me',
            'type'=>'primary',
            'htmlOptions'=>array(
            'onclick'=>'js:bootbox.alert("hello world")'
    ),
    ));
    ?>
    }

Answer (score 0):

It will be quite long so i didnt post in comentary. To achieve what you want, you don't actually need button. You can make it as link, or even some container, just apply styling.
So start with code:

```
<?php echo $form->checkBoxRow($model, 'default'); ?>
<div class="form-actions">
    //some div or link here - doesnt matter, lets call it #sub_button
</div>
```

Now add js to your div(link), in html or bind click on document ready.

```
<div id="sub_button" onclick=getModal()>
<?php
if ($model->isNewRecord) echo 'Create' ;
else echo 'Save'
?>
</div>
```

Now write your getModal() function:

```
function getModal(){
    if (($('#default').prop("checked")){
    //show here your dialog or modal window
    //if you need to pass some data or render it - use ajax 
    //$().dialog() if its simple jui 
    }
    else {}//show some notification or what you want here 
}
```

And 1 more - dont mix js with php. You cant use php in js, for this purposes exists ajax. Only thing you can do - echo php value to js variable. Also you cant pass js variables to php, only via ajax.